# Android build is failing when trying to build with ndk16

Tags: arm64

I am trying to build arm64 apk with ndk16 using ruby. Why is it failing. It seems to be some jni issue.

I am using gcc compiler toolchain to build the apk

It should build arm64 apk with gcc toolchain.

Comment: Hi, you should provide some details and codes/logs. We can't help you without further details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC is not supported in ARM64 and try using CLANG compiler with NDK19 and above.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Akash, I will try using ndk19.